# How to solve "Failure Sending Mail" error while sending email using SMTP

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I am trying to send an e-mail using SMTP on C# but I am getting error "Failure Sending Mail"
I would just like to ask if my code below is correct

```
    private void SendMail()
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient();

        mail.From = new MailAddress(MailConst.From);
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("recepient@gmail.com"));
        mail.Subject = "Test";
        mail.Body = "This is a test";

        mailClient.Host = MailConst.SmtpServer;
        mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        mailClient.Port = 465;
        mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
        mailClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(MailConst.Username, MailConst.Password);
        try
        {
            mailClient.Send(mail);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            WriteErrorOutput(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public class MailConst
    {
        public static string Username = "user";
        public static string Password = "pass";
        public const string SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";

        public static string From = Username + "@gmail.com";

    }
```

I keep on getting the exception "Failure to send message".

And when I try to open the exception to see what's wrong it says "Command 'Debug.QuickWatch' is not available."

Appreciate your time and your help in answering my questions.

Thank you.

EDIT:

Finally able to see the inner exception, seems like my connection was rejected.
Checked with our network admin and he said that Gmail SMTP is blocked in our network.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: You need to post inner exception there could be many reasons why you are getting this error

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to check the connection

To run the telnet and test on a Windows in your computer:

```
1.Open the Start menu, and select Run.
2.Enter command in the Open: field, and click OK.
3.Enter 'telnet smtp.gmail.com 465,' and hit Enter, or enter 'telnet smtp.gmail.com 587' instead.
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this..

```
  private void SendMail()
  {
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

    mail.From = new MailAddress(MailConst.From);
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("recepient@gmail.com"));
    mail.Subject = "Test";
    mail.Body = "This is a test";

    mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
    mailClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(MailConst.Username, MailConst.Password);
    try
    {
        mailClient.Send(mail);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        WriteErrorOutput(ex.Message);
    }
  }
```